# Not able to use package in version 4.6.1 in ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-core

I created a ASP.NET Core RC2 class library and on project.json I have:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net461": { },
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
      }
    },
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

I used it on an ASP.Net Core RC2 web application which project.json has:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "TestLibrary": "1.0.0",
},

"frameworks": {
  "net461": { }
},
```

NOTE: I omitted the other dependencies for sake of simplicity.

I get the following error when trying to restore the Web Project:

```
The dependency TestLibrary 1.0.0 does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I changed my TestLibrary configuration to:

```
"dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
},

"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.5": {
    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net452+win81"
    ]
  }
}
```

But I have a class library project name TestLibraryTests with tests:

```
"testRunner": "xunit",

"dependencies": {
  "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
  "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
  "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10015",
  "TestLibrary": "1.0.0"
},

"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.5": {
    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net452+win81"
    ]
  }
}
```

But now I get the error:

```
Package dotnet-test-xunit 1.0.0-rc2-build10015 is not compatible with netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5). Package dotnet-test-xunit 1.0.0-rc2-build10015 supports:
  - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
  - netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.
```

What am I missing? I can't use XUnit with RC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a class library package, make sure you are choosing the .NET Core-->Class Library, but also make sure you choose the right target framework from the dropdown circled red in the imaged below.

[image: .NET Package]

Your project.json should then look like this:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I get a problem with XUnit on the tests of my class library. Do you know how to solve it? I just added an update to my question. Thank You,

Comment: it looks like you are mixing the .net framework 4.5.2 and 4.5.1...choose one version, go with the 4.5.1 and then change the frameworks everywhere to "portable-net45+win81"

Answer (score 1):

When I tried using the package directly without installing the .NET Core RC2 first I got the same error :)

**Blog Post:** https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2/

**Download:**
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935/file/77371/8/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe?SRC=VSIDE&UPDATE=TRUE

Comment: You miss umderstood my question. I installed rc2 and i am using it without any problem. The problem is when i create a class library project publish its package and then try to use it on a web project.